# Unknown Attributes on nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I'm having trouble getting my InventoryItem to accept nested attributes which is strange.

In my script/console, I did the following:

```
>> InventoryItem.create!(:name => 'what', :image_attributes => [ {:image => File.open("/home/davidc/Desktop/letterbx.jpg", "r") }])
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: image_attributes
```

I am not sure why I'm getting the unknown attribute error when in my model, I already did accept_nested_attributes.

I'm using Rails v2.3.5.

Inventory Item Model

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  uuid_it

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
  has_many :images, :validate => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

Image

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inventory_item

  has_attached_file :image, :style => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `has_many :images`
So, it should be `:images_attributes`, not `:image_attributes`

```
InventoryItem.create!(:name => 'what', :images_attributes => [ {:image => File.open("/home/davidc/Desktop/letterbx.jpg", "r") }])
```

And it is correct to use array of hashes when you have `has_many` relationship

Answer (score 0):

`:image_attributes` is supposed to be a hash.

```
InventoryItem.create!(
   :name => 'what',
   :image_attributes => { ... }
)
```